# Magento 2: Allow to select swatch and option of Out of Stock product of Configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1.7

I have to allow customer to select Out of Stock product options and after this selection display stock status.

I have checked all things related this but m not getting any solution.

Please provide me some solution.